# Search for files containing specific string in text file in unix

Tags: shell, ksh

i am new in writing a shell script and would like to search for a specific string in files with extension "*RETURN.DAT" in a directory. the strings i want to look for are in a separate file. what unix commands should i use? i am mixed up using find and grep. i also need to copy the files i found in another directory. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are *in **a** directory* you don't need `find` (`man find`: *search for files in a directory hierarchy*) but instead you can point `grep` to search from that directory:

```
$ grep search_term path/to/a/dir/*.DAT
```

Since *the strings [you] want to look for are in a separate file*, `man grep`:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
       Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used
       multiple times or is combined with  the  -e  (--regexp)  option,
       search  for  all  patterns  given.  The empty file contains zero
       patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

So:

```
$ grep -f separate_file path/to/a/dir/*.DAT`
```

should do the job.